# Google Maps API key for Android Wear

Tags: android, google-maps, wear-os

I have an Android handheld application and I want to add a wear app for it.

My handheld app already uses Google Maps API and has a key for it. Now I add a 'wear' module to my project in Android Studio and I want my wear app to contain a full screen map. I've implemented an activity with a map but I have troubles starting it. So I presumed there can be a key issue. Do I have to get a new key for wear?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the same key as your handheld app (provided you use the same key signature) and to authorize the package name of your apk watch in your account google map api.